# How to find the projection vector of an arbitary vector on a plane?

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, projective-space

I have a 3D coordinate system defined by 3 perpendicular basis vectors (p), (q) and (r). On the other hand, I have an arbitary vector (d). I would like to find the vector (s), which is the projection of (d) on to one of the planes (w). p, q and r are normalized.

This is the visual representation of what I am trying to achieve:

[[image: ]]

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your plane is defined by the normalized vectors $\vec r$ and $\vec q$?.
($|\vec r|=1$ and $|\vec q|=1$)
Then the projected vector $\vec s$ of $\vec d$ on this plane is simply:

$$\vec s = \left(\vec r\cdot \vec d\right)\vec r + \left(\vec q\cdot \vec d\right)\vec q$$

Comment: Yes, (r) and (q) are normalized. So, I dot (r) and (d) and multiply the result by (r) and then sum with (q) dot (d) times (q). Just checking if I got the annotation of the solution right. I will try it now. Thanks.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.